# How to express this simple equation in terms of a different variable?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, substitution

I am using the equation:

$$y=(1-e^{-ax})*d$$

For the shape of a logarithmic attack phase of an audio synthesizer envelope. The idea is for it to go from (0,0) to (t,1) at a given time (x=t) value.

I therefore need to solve the equation for "a" or "d" by substituting (t,1) as:

$$1=(1-e^{-at})*d$$

I can solve it easily enough for "d" which gives:

$$y=(1-e^{-ax})*(e^{at}/(e^{at}-1))$$

I have graphed this at Desmos and it works with control of the curve by "a" and time "t", where "t" is the point at which y=1:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k432jwmhzm

However, I would ideally like it to be controlled by "d" and "t" rather than "a" and "t".

Can the equation above (2nd in this post) be solved for "a" instead to result in an equation controlled by "d" and "t"?

I only need valid output between (0,0) and (t,1), where t>0.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it can!

Notice that

$$\begin{align}1 = (1 - e^{-at})d &\iff \frac{1}{d} = 1 - e^{-at}\\
&\iff e^{-at} = 1 - \frac{1}{d}\\
&\iff -at = \log\left( 1 - \frac{1}{d} \right)\\
&\iff a = -\frac{\log\left( 1 - \frac{1}{d} \right)}{t}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! Very much. Works very nicely: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/byatlxg546

Comment: Glad I could help. Notice how solving for $a$ wasn't necessarily difficult. One just needed to solve for $e^{-at}$ first, then apply logarithms to both sides.

Comment: $\ln$ should be used instead of $\log$, shouldn’t it?

Comment: @KM101 Outside of high school, $\log$ is actually used to represent the natural logarithm, so by $\log$ I mean $\log_e$, and not $\log_{10}$. In a calculator, this would've been $\ln$, but only because calculators go against this "norm".

Comment: Ah, okay. I was guessing that were the case, but just wanted to make sure. Thanks.